# How to endif in Flask Jinja2 templating engine. Getting TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'session'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, templating-engine

I'm building a website using [the Flask Framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and I now run into an error which I don't understand. For the simple base.html file I pasted below I'm gettig a `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'session'`, even though I clearly end the if with the `{% endif %}`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<!doctype html>
<div class="page">
    <div class="metanav">
        {% if not in session.logged_in %}
            aa
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the following line, the code is missing an operand for `not in` operator.

```
{% if ?? not in session.logged_in %}
      ^^
```

Or, you maybe mean `not` operator:

```
{% if not session.logged_in %}
```

Comment: I indeed meant the `not` operator. I totally read over the `in` coming after that. I guess it was just a stupid habit doing typing thw `in` after the `not`. Thanks a million!